# Downloading file based on last modified date fails if older than 1 day

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-requests

Below is a code snippet which downloads a file based on last modified date between server and local.

```
try:
    url = "https://10.10.10.10/version.ini"
    local_ini = ".//config/version.ini"
    filetime = (time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(local_ini))))
    print("File Last Modified: {0}".format(filetime))
    r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
    meta = r.headers['last-modified']
    logging.info("Web  Last Modified: {0}".format(meta))
    if filetime < meta:
        print("Newer file found! Downloading...")
        if r != False:
            try:
                fileName = os.path.basename(urlparse.urlsplit(r.url)[2])
                with open(".//config/version.ini"e, 'wb') as f:
                     shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw,f)    
            finally:
                r.close()
    else:
        logging.info('No new version found. You got the latest file!') 

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  
    logging.info(e)
```

When I modify the file in same day I get the correct result:

```
File Last Modified: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 03:42:23 GMT
Web  Last Modified: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 03:44:22 GMT
Newer file found! Downloading...
```

But when I modify a file, after one day I get the wrong result :

```
File Last Modified: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 08:38:38 GMT
Web  Last Modified: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 02:44:45 GMT
No new version found. You got the latest file!
```

Why is the timestamp compare giving the wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example meta is a string, not a `time` object.  If you compare two `datetime` objects you will have better luck:

```
if (dt.datetime.strptime(filetime, '%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT') < 
        dt.datetime.strptime(meta, '%a, %d %b %Y %X GMT')):
```

you will need:

```
 import datetime as dt
```

Comment: i am getting TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not str

Comment: I misread your code, I edited the example to use datetime objects.